# Why the Community ♦ user accounts aren't connected between them?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-accounts, community-user

I see that each Stack Exchange site has a Community ♦ user that keeps the sites clean.

For example:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com//users/-1/community)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community)
- etc

We see that the Community ♦ user has the userid `-1`.

My question is: why they aren't connected between them?

Even on [this](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) page we see all Community users from all sites, in each profile only Area51 account is present.

> [image]

Comment: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bot, it does what it wants.  We gave up trying to control it after "the incident."  If you saw what it did to Mike, just...no, we can't, poor Mike.

Comment: I'm sorry, Nick, I can't let you do t-CARRY ON EVERYTHING IS FINE.

Comment: You've given it too much freedom! It's now [destroying this quaint little beta site!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/178438)

Comment: What incident are you talking about?

Comment: @DonaldDuck We don't like to talk about it.

Answer (score 4):

It got account on each and every site in the Stack Exchange network. In the past it used to show them all in the profile page, until they changed it to show only the top five accounts and link to the full list on the network profile page.

Since all the Community user's accounts are "equal" with 1 reputation there's no point in showing just five so they decided to ditch it and show only the Area 51 account - not 100% sure, maybe just to have *something* in there.

Comment: One interesting thing is that it is logged in all the time as it is automated operated account, but it's `last seen` time never gets updated like our profile does.

Comment: @Lucifer Its a ghost.

Comment: @Lucifer it's not really "logged in"; there's no human being actually logging in as that user, it doesn't have OpenID. It's just records in the database that getting updated by automated processes. The "last seen" was manually updated by a dev, guess they don't really have time to keep it always up to date. :-)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd that's what it wants you to think.