# Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual

Tags: support, community-user, bump

On [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/):

[image: enter image description]

These are all Community ♦ bumps, separated by exactly one hour (They occur on `hour`:38:16 UTC). Could the bot be sedated please? We're a 4-questions-per-day site; a bump an hour is not good for business.

We used to have one bump per day. This is evident if you scroll down on the homepage and check the timestamps ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MshhE.jpg)).

Apparently the number of questions bumped per hour is a [configuration value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped/48579#comment112509_48579). Maybe this got tweaked?

Comment: FWIW, one question per hour is exactly the pace that the community user is designed to do, so it's unlikely that it changed recently.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not on Chem. (see update)

Comment: Since it's gone wild, you might have to use a tranquilizer dart.

Comment: @Manishearth ah, after checking the timestamps it does appear that you are correct. You should update your screenshots with what it shows before Community went on a spree.

Comment: I fear [the team lost control over that bot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184403/152859)! :P

Comment: @Undo: I _can_ suspend it, but I'll get yelled at if I do it :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd they never had control. Control is an illusion, created by Community. The only one with control now is... Mr. Skeet!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Ha! How do we pray to the Skeet again?

Comment: @Manishearth first, you chant his name 3 times... then, you spin around twice, light 5 candles, do the skeet-u-flect, and drink a bowl of milk, because that sounds like fun. There, you've successfully prayed to our god, Mr. Skeet.

Comment: @Richard I think that just buying [one of his books](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Jon-Skeet/e/B001JP0M8K) would suffice. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that's like paying a tithe or something, not prayer.

Comment: @Richard OK, but doing what you said before while holding a book of Him would greatly increase chances for response, right? :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Our god does not offer guarantees of any kind on his prayers, and is not responsible for any jobs lost due to performing the prayer rituals at work.

Comment: @Sha Your Skeetage may vary.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No change to the configuration value so far as I can see - it's max 1 per hour (which is what you're observing).

Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one *non-deleted* answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

There's a pretty reasonable chance that you just didn't have very many questions meeting those criteria until today...

Comment: Are questions having an answer (or answers) scoring less than 0 bumped?

Comment: @hims056 from own experience - no.

Comment: I suggest linking to this answer from Community's profile, as is done for auto-deletion. This would prevent [confusion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252233/).

Comment: This suggests that questions with no answers aren't bumped (or weren't two years ago when this was written).  I'm pretty sure I've seen Community bumps of truly-unanswered questions.  Is this out of date or am I seeing something else at play?  (I'm pretty sure I've seen this on sites I moderate, so I don't mean questions bumped by deleted spam.)

Comment: You may also see this when an anonymous edit is applied, @monica

Comment: @Shog9 Is this answer still current? I can't puzzle out why [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/math-rendering-errors) got bumped.

Comment: Was last bumped on the 5th... After that, the answer got two upvotes, @E.P., making it ineligible for further bumping. IOW, the system worked. See: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/posts/7513/timeline

Comment: @Shog9 Gah! sorry, I got lost in the timelines and assumed that any upvotes on the answer would show on the thread timeline (which I think used to be the case?). Sorry to bother you, and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, the old timeline rolled question and answer events into one lump, which was nice on occasion but usually just confusing as hell.

Comment: @Shog9 locked question seem to be able to be bumped, this bug; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210458/questions-auto-bumped-by-the-community-user-even-though-they-are-locked just re-appeared

Comment: Funny thing... I have no idea why I put "locked" in there to begin with, @yagmoth555 - there's no mention of it in the code, nor - so far as I can see - has there ever been.

Comment: @Shog9 hehe, well the word lock kinda maked sense for me, as if locked, the community can't upvote or downvote (or add an answer), no way to stop the bump :) (from a community's view)

Comment: oh, it makes sense, @yagmoth555 - except that I can't find nor think of a single example where locking bump-eligible questions makes sense to begin with. See my answer on that bug report you linked.