# Questions auto bumped by the Community User even though they are locked

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-user, bump, locked-questions

https://serverfault.com/questions/159509/printer-on-different-networkip-range-can-i-print-to-it

This question on Server Fault was just bumped to the front page like any other question that has no upvoted answers and is a bit old. The thing is, it's been locked. Shouldn't these be treated as "closed" questions and not be poked to the front page? The [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511) says that locked and closed questions aren't bumped.

As of today, the question has been bumped every month, and received its last bump 2 days ago.

The whole point of bumping these posts is to get new contributions, but a locked post can't have any content added or revised.

[image: Community bumped post]

---

**Edited**: as of today, 2017-03-30, the same question is yet again bumped:

[image]

Comment: Retagged as a bug, because [documentation says](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511) locked questions are not supposed to be bumped.

Comment: Also, this same question just got bumped again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ordinary lock does prevent auto bump, however in this case it's historical lock which is different. Retagged. /cc @Norm

Comment: I confirm that the same question just got re-bumped today..

Answer (score 13):

The "documentation" was wrong; the guy who wrote that was full of crap.

As far as I can tell, the system has *never* stopped locked questions from being bumped - they just tend to not qualify for other reasons (no answers, deleted, etc.).

In fact, it's extremely unusual to end up with a locked question that has nothing better than 0-scored answers: out of the 1.9 million questions on Stack Overflow that qualify for bumping as I type this, there are exactly *two* that are locked - one for a "content dispute" and another for "off-topic comments". (I've now unlocked them both.)

Excluding Stack Overflow, there are only 7 locked, bumpable questions *anywhere else on the network* - all of them locked for "historical significance", which means they'll *never stop being bumped* since the answers can never be upvoted or downvoted. I reviewed and deleted all of them, which takes care of the immediate problem.

Long-term, the proper fix here is to ensure locking is used responsibly; there's rarely ever a reason to leave a question locked for months or years at a time, and even more rarely a reason to use "historical significance" on unanswered questions - I'll make a note to review the guidance in place here.

Comment: +1 for predictable self-deprecation!

Comment: Looks like this is happening again; see [Bumped locked question is not visible on web, but visible in apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317100/bumped-locked-question-is-not-visible-on-web-but-visible-in-apps).