# Locked question "bumped" by Community bot doesn't appear at top of homepage on web, but does appear at top in apps/the API

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api, bump, locked-questions

According to [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210458/339911), bumping locked questions to the homepage is by design. I disagree with this, but my question is about a different, but related, issue.

A couple of times (and today is one of these), I noticed that a [locked question that is bumped](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2775/176217) to the homepage is not visible on the [homepage of the website](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image: web]

But it's still visible in mobile apps, i.e. on iOS:

> [image: ios]

And on Android:

> [image: android]

Since the both apps are affected, I suppose that the problem is in the Stack Exchange API, rather than in the apps themselves.

Comment: Confirmed that [the API does show it as recently active](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.meta.stackoverflow&run=true) (currently in top 3).

Comment: I would flag a moderator, as the lock is not used correctly I think, as shog9 state it, it should not happen  (locked and its eligible to bump)

Answer (score 4):

I expect this is by design. This feed from the API and apps doesn't correspond to the homepage of the website (which filters out heavily downvoted questions too, unlike the app/API). It corresponds to the [active tab under /questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active), which has no filtering that I know of.

For example, consider the question [What are good places to post your work where it will be read by others?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904/34330). Some moderator had the gall to edit it, and now if you look at all the questions on [the active tab of questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=active), you can see the bump (currently page 3 but that will rapidly change):

[image: that question shown as edited by Laurel]

(Frustratingly, the post doesn't show as locked here. It definitely should though.)

My personal opinion is that the homepage shouldn't be filtered as this has led to some abuse going mostly undetected, namely vandalism of downvoted posts.

Answer (score 3):

While it can be easy to miss, Laurel's answer is correct - there is no "homepage" equivalent in the app - it's the "Questions" page, which you can tell by looking at the tabs and the heading -

[image: Screenshot of the main page of MSE in the iOS app - the heading is circled, which reads "Questions" and "Meta Stack Exchange" as is the tab in the lower left corner which has a Q in a speech bubble and has the word "Questions" under it.]

The front page (homepage) is titled "Top Questions", not just "Questions".

Considering this, and the fact that, when I compare the app "Questions" page to the site's "Questions" page (both sorted by "active") I get identical results, I've marked this as status-bydesign. While I understand your concern, comparing the homepage to the Questions page is like comparing apples to oranges. We [intentionally exclude some content from the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/284336) e.g. questions scoring -4 or lower (-8 or lower on meta) and questions with the historical lock.