# Community user - poke old unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, community-user

I am curious to know if the Community user really pokes unanswered questions.

Community User profile says:

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some
>   attention

In my past experience I have seen Community poke questions which have a answer but it was not accepted. I have never seen a poke by Community which has no answer (not even unaccepted one). Am I missing something?

I believe as one of the prime objective of Community User is to poke unanswered questions. I do not want to bump my questions or any specific question. I am curious to know why Community User does not seems to poke question having no answer at all?

Answer (score 1):

In Stack Exchange, "unanswered" means a question that either has no answers whatsoever *or* the answers it does have do not have a score greater than 0 and none has been accepted.

Per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/262755):

> The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that [have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/262755).

So what you're seeing is by design.

Comment: i feel it could have been directed towards question having no answers at all. why to poke question for which a one time unregistered user raised and forgot to accept. if the question is bad it will be purged if not it will be noticed.

Comment: @Pushpak You're assuming that the question author validated the answer and found it to be a correct quality answer.  Since they never acted on it, we *don't* in fact know that.  The answer could be worthless, or at least low quality/incorrect.  We won't even have any basis for discussing its quality until some users have voted on it.

Comment: @servy point noted