# Typo on malware page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

On https://stackexchange.com/about/malware , the second sentence reads:

> Please report any site proxing our content to Google here:
> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport

That probably should be 'Proxying'.

Comment: Oh come on, the page says *right there* not to post serious security issues publicly on a meta site. ;)

Comment: I hope you also reported the site you landed on originally to Google @Joe

Comment: @AnnaLear But if I send it via email I won't get imaginary unicorn points!

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Actually this came from another question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296142/fake-stackoverflow-site) - I didn't land on the page directly.  But of course I would if I had.

Comment: Even if you didn't land on it directly please report it, we need the reports!

Comment: @GeoffDalgas No problem - done.

Comment: Somebody mind answering so I can mark this accepted?  (Or is that not done on bug reports?)

Comment: @Joe A [status-completed] tag is generally sufficient to mark a bug as fixed.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Meh, the Community user will still cheerfully bump status-completed but unanswered bug reports. Doesn't hurt to post a quick answer. Not *necessary*, but helpful. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear If a question has no answer at all, [Community will not bump it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/). (I do agree that having an answer is better.).

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Hmm, I stand corrected. Can never remember how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typo was fixed.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks for indulging my OCD (and for fixing it)!