# Change the community user bumps to include questions with a negatively scored answer

Tags: feature-request, community-user, bump

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/203972) the community user bumps questions when:

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).

I'd like to suggest that questions with a negatively scored answer should be bumped as well, the reasons I'd put forward are:

- If the question is actually a decent one that's received a poor answer it should be bumped so someone can provide a quality answer.
- If the question is low quality one unlikely to get a good answer it should be put in front of the community again so it can be closed.

Maybe these could be given a lower priority so it wouldn't affect larger sites like Stack Overflow, but on smaller sites where community bumps can be less frequent at the moment these questions often get left in limbo as unanswered questions.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for bumping is not "this question needs a better answer". If it was, the questions with no answer would be bumped, and they are not.

The reason is "this question may already have an answer that hasn't been recognized as such". It's brought forward so a decision can be made: there is a decent answer (voted up) or no, the attempted answer isn't useful (voted down).

Bumping questions in need of answers would be annoying, especially on smaller and slower sites. There are far too many questions in need of (better) answers; the may be good (and upvoted), but don't get an answer because nobody on the site knows an answer. They may eventually be answered when someone with specific expertise in that question joins the site; indeed, some people join precisely to answer such a question, after it comes up in their search results. But until that happens, repeatedly shoving the question in the face of regular users is just an annoyance.