# Why does the Community ♦︎︎ user only bump questions with at least one answer?

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/339911) to [Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485), Community ♦︎︎ user bumps questions which "have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0".

I can't understand why having answers is a reason to bump, i.e. why questions without answers are not bumped too? Ceteris paribus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the Community ♦︎︎ user only bumps questions which "have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0" because:

- the bumping is targeted at trying to move questions that the community has been interested enough to try and answer off of the Unanswered list
- a question with no answers suggests its asker has not continued to try and edit/garden it until it attracts an answerer and so, if it does not have the community showing any interest in it via upvoting and editing, the question is left in the path of the Roomba
- it would be inefficient to have a question that no one is interested enough to answer, or to improve into an answerable state, left to keep cycling through hoping to attract an answer during the next bump because:

  - a question with a 0 votes answer only needs a single upvote during the bump to come off the Unanswered list
  - a question with no answers needs much more volunteered effort to first get an answer written (especially if the asker thinks their job is done), and then also an upvote before it comes off the Unanswered list.

Comment: Agreed with most of your points. But is it not counter-productive to only bump the question several times for waiting someone to vote for the answer? I think a question with only one answer with 0 score is not an indicator of much more interest for community than question without answers at all.

Comment: @alexolut the auto bump is also sort of "call for action", i.e. if the answer got 0 score, it means it might need an edit to become better, or if can't become better, maybe it needs a flag and be deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard does it mean that question without any answers no need to "call for action"?

Comment: @alexolut the action is for the answer, in case of auto bump. Question with no answers is different issue, and if zero or negative score, it will be auto deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard perhaps this is the main point, which is worth to understand that auto bump is for an answer, not for questions.