# How to resurface questions that weren't answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, unanswered-questions

I'm sure that someone has brought this up before, but I can't find it. On some stack exchange sites, particularly smaller ones, not all questions get answered straight away. This means that a question which hasn't gotten answered will get less and less attention, making no-one answer it. Is there any way for these questions to be 'recovered' so that people can see them?

If someone is looking for a question to answer, they will look for the most recent questions on the site, or most recent on a tag, if it is a large site like stack overflow. This means people generally don't look at old questions, as they are probably already answered. How can these questions be resurfaced?

Also, people typically don't want to waste their time on answering that already has an answer, even if the answer is not accepted. This means that questions which have been answered, but with a bad answer, don't get the attention they need.

**In short, how can we create an environment such that question answerers can see questions that should be seen?**

Comment: You might be interested in [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327229/questions-of-a-specific-tag-that-tend-towards-auto-deletion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You edit to improve. You bounty. You let the system bump things up.

I suppose in a small enough site, with an enthusiastic enough community, a little informal competition - or even awareness of it helps. Meta posts with statistics seem to be a thing for example, and since people on meta are already engaged users, they may hunt for things to answer.

While I rely on the front page - I also sometimes look to see if I can add my answer to an existing question which matches a problem I solved.

. I'm not just answering for the original question poster - I'm also hoping the next guy, and the next guy find my answer useful. Getting past "Also, people typically don't want to waste their time on answering that already has an answer, even if the answer is not accepted." is pretty important.

Comment: How exactly does the system bump things up? I’ve sometimes seen this happen, but is there a link that you could give me to explain how it does it?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped I was specifically thinking of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511