# Which sites impose limits on Community bumps, and what are those limits?

Tags: support, community-user, bump

Most sites don't have limits on how many questions can be bumped by the Community user, based on past bumps: regardless of how many questions were bumped in the past and are currently on the home page, they continue to bump questions every hour.

There are some that don't always do, however, per Shog's [message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7542448#7542448):

> [Certain] sites only allow *n* bumped questions on the homepage at a time, and will refuse to bump more until some roll off
>
> jmac pushed for that for Japanese.SO, since almost everyone using it was in the same timezone so they'd go to bed and... Wake up to a page full of bumps

They didn't mention the exact limit for Japanese Stack Overflow or the other sites with a similar limitation.

Also, another feature of the above category (but not the same one) [was just implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350953/377214) for Hardware Recommendations today: if one of the last five recently active questions has been bumped and is currently on the home page, no questions will be bumped.

Can I please get a full list of sites which limit Community bumps based on prior such recent bumps, and how exactly they limit them?

Comment: The main FAQ on questions being bumped: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/335251)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you note, there's a site setting that CMs/devs can adjust to prevent the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/335251) from [bumping a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/335251) if another post has recently been bumped. Specifically, this site setting lets us specify a custom value such that the Community user will not bump posts if at least one in the top N, sorted by activity date, has been bumped. (By default, this setting is not enabled.)

These are the sites that have this setting enabled (with N set to the specified value):

1. [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/) (set to 5), as a result of [this request](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2675/39853)
2. [ExpressionEngine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/) (set to 5), following [this post on their Meta](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1315/11412)
3. [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) (set to 5), as a result of [this request](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2936/124431)
4. [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (set to 5), as a result of [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347323/335251)
5. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (set to 5), as a result of [this request](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9842/779485)
6. [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (set to 5), following [this request](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2121/47948)
7. [Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) (set to 10) – no request on their Meta, but a CM enabled this due to the site's front page being mostly Community-bumped posts (as a result of low activity on the site)

---

(For reference, there's also a different site setting that controls the maximum number of questions that Community can bump per hour; the default value is 1.)

Comment: (I'm not going to commit to keeping this post up to date if/when other sites have this site setting enabled or we change the value it's set to, but feel free to update it as needed.)

Comment: You appear to be doing just fine so far. Thanks!