# Community User's network profile > activity tab is crashing

Tags: bug, community-user, network-profile, activity

Two things I found unusual on [Community User's Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community):

1. [accounts tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) shows only Area51 account. -- This looks previously discussed as [Why the Community ♦ user accounts aren't connected between them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184385/260388)
2. [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) is crashing:

   > Oops! Something Bad Happened!

So, Why clicking on activity tab is crashing?